# Why my app closes when user deny permmisions?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to use camera for my Xamarin Forms App, so when the permmision is dennied the app crashes, how can I handle that responde (Not allow using camera). ZXing asks for permissions

This is my code from my Android Main Activiy in Xamarin Forms

```
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

I would like to handle when the user deny permission, not allowing it to crash my app

Answer (score 1):

In the code where you attempt to use the camera, there needs to be a check if you have permission. You can decide how to handle it from there (ask again, notify that you can't proceed without this permission, etc.). If you try to do something assuming the user already said yes to the permission, then it will crash with some type of permission related exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it helps

`global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions, grantResults);`

or

Reverting to ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.3.2 and ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms 2.3.2

said in the link below

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96719/why-is-zxing-net-mobile-crashing-after-camera-permission